# Agregar imagen en cuerpo del correo outlook

Tags: python, selenium

estoy tratando de agregar una imagen al correo de outlook y lo resuelvo como archivo adjunto, pero lo que necesito es que la imagen valla en el cuerpo del correo.

Este es mi codigo el cual capturo una imagen del navegador con selenium y luego se adjunta al correo para ser enviada.

```
    # Uso Selenium para tomar una captura de pantalla y guardarlo como una imagen
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("file://" + os.path.abspath("vista1.html"))
    time.sleep(3) # espera 3 segundos antes de tomar el screenshot
    driver.save_screenshot("img1.png")
    path_to_image = os.path.abspath("img1.png")
    driver.quit()
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = destinatarios
    mail.Subject = "Resumen Semanal de Sismos CDA"
    mail.Body = summary_message
    mail.Attachments.Add(path_to_image)
    mail.Send()
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Aquí https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/ tienes tres formas de hacerlo. Básicamente consiste en enviar el mensaje en HTML y poner un tag html img con el enlace adecuado.

Las tres posibilidades son la forma de poner el enlace. Como imagen adjunta al correo y usando una url estilo "cid:imagen.png", embebiendo los bytes completos de la imagen en codificacion base64, o bien simplemente poniendo un enlace normal http a una URL de alguna web que tenga la imagen.

Se bueno.